# Extract values from numpy array with condition on strings

Tags: python, numpy

So this is my first post here and English is not my native language, I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I have a numpy array coming frome a shape (basically a table of data) containing the following :

```
[('information1',   'identifier1',              length1)
('information2',    'identifier2',              length2)
('information3',    'identifier3,identifier4',  length3)
....
]
```

where :

- `informationx` is a `string`,
- `identifier` is a `string` containing one or multiple ids in one `string`,
- `length` is a `float`.

I need to extract from this array all the rows containing information about one identifier.

In SQL I would do

```
select * from array where id like "%identifier1%"
```

It's easy when there's only one identifier :

```
extract = array[array[id_header] == identifier1]
```

Is there any elegant and pythonic way to do so (maybe through extract, select or where) ?

Comment: I would actually use pandas for that, so that the floats stay floats. So what is the issue you have? This should work, doesn't it?

Comment: The issue I have is I don't know how to 'translate' the SQLish statement into python to extract the information from my array. This will work in sql, but I'm looking for the trick in python. I'll look into pandas though.

Comment: What is the issue you have with the translation you have?

Comment: I'm looking for the equivalent (if it exists) of "select * from array where id like "%identifier1%"" in python using numpy. I know the equivalent of "select * from array where id = 'identifier1'" is array[array[id_header] == identifier1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a easy task in pandas,considering you can use pandas, translate your array to a pandas dataframe, using
`import pandas as pd
df = pd.dataFrame([your_array]) #creating data_frame
df.columns = ['col_1','col_2','col_3'] #setting column names`

considering you had set names col_1,col_2,col_3 to your  columns.

subselect the columns that you want with this code.

```
df_subset = df[ df['col_2'].str.contains('identifierx') ] #subselecting the data frame.
```

Considering you can't use pandas, only using numpy.

```
new_lis = []
for idx in range(0,len(your_array)):
    if( 'identifierx' in your_array[idx][1]):
        new_lis.append(your_array[idx])
```

Comment: Yeah that looks great ! Except I did not manage to install pandas in my Arcgis10.2 python. I'm still on it.

Comment: It works, thank you. Similar to Jacob's proposal but this version with len() works.

Comment: ok, mark my answer as the right if that helped you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could do a loop to go through each index to see if the identifier is the one you want:

```
 lengths = []
 for i in range(array.size[0]): #this should iterate through each row in the table 
      if array[i][1] == "identifierx":
           lengths.append(array[i][2]) #adds the lenghts to a list containing all the lengths from the identifier you want
```

Comment: I get the following error : for i in range(arr_support.size[0]):
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'.

Comment: @Seb this is because array.size shouldn't return multiple values, I shouldn't have used it. it was just supposed to represent the number of rows in the table/array. However many rows are in the table, you should put that in for the range.

Answer (score 0):

That's a beautiful numpy solution! Just wanted to add the list comp version:

Ran these over a (1000012, 3) array with the above values padded in to query the search and got the below timings:

```
%%time
new_lis = []
for idx in range(0,len(huge_data)):
    if('identifier3' in huge_data[idx][1]):
        new_lis.append(huge_data[idx])
```

Returns Wall time: 875 ms

For the list comp:

```
new_lis = [idx for idx in range(0, len(huge_data)) if ('identifier3' in huge_data[idx][1])]
```

Returns Wall time: 772 ms

But yeah - I tried to solve with list comp + numpy indices but to catch the string I used a *regular expression* so it slowed it down to ~4.5s **wah waaaah**.

Good question, good answers!